# MySQL connections limit in Micro CloudFoundry

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

I'm running my application with the Micro CloudFoundry, but I'm having trouble connecting to MySQL 'User 'usGh0jJk8EoZn' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource'. How can I change this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as ebottard said, it's well worth making sure your code isn't leaking connections. But, if you want to change the mysql setup for the instance running on Micro CloudFoundry, you can SSH in to the VM using the 'vcap' user.

Once connected, you will find the mysql configuration file at /var/vcap/jobs/mysql_node/config/my.cnf

For maximum connections you will also have to change the max_user_conns value in /var/vcap/jobs/mysql_node/config/mysql_node.yml

Please also take a look at;

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/infrastructure/micro/using-mcf.html#logging-in-to-micro-cloud-foundry

Comment: I just change the mysql_node.yml and put max_user_conns = 0 (unlimited)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure you can change that value.

Before going down that road though, you may want to make sure that you are not leaking connections. Is your application running correctly when deployed locally (*i.e.* not using regular CloudFoundry nor Micro CF)? How are you connecting to the database? It may seem strange that you hit a connection limit if you're actually the sole user of your app, which I assume you are if using micro.